# Hiding protected functions and members from the user?

Tags: c++

My classes are event driven so for example, the public mouseClick() calls the protected onMouseClick().

I find that it might be puzzling if the user's intellisense picks up on all the protected ones. Is there a way to minimize this confusion in any way?

Thanks

Comment: The only way to do that is to make it **BIG** in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, but that is not up to you, but up to the user configuring his IDE correctly. Usually, including private or protected members in auto-completion etc. is disabled, but if a user of your class library wants it, that is not for you to decide (or influence in any way, since that is not possible).

Comment: Let's be thankful when the intellisense *works* at all, let alone when it accidentally does more than needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member access control in C++ is for compilers, not for users. If you really need that, you should use ABCs as interfaces and create your objects through factories. This way you can make sure no end-user ever has to see any non-interface part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Good implementation of intellisense should not pick them up. I don't think there isn't much you can do to prevent it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

[The editorbrwsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) atribute is used by intellisense to know wheter the user should see the method or not. While a blanket option is probably available in intellisense to hide protected functions, but if all else fails, you could use this.